# Why isn't my passing by reference working?

Tags: c++

I can't figure out why my passing by reference is not working? I have googled how to fix it but nothing seems to explain it good enough for me to understand. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
void celsius_to_fahrenheit(double celsius);
void get_celsius(double &);

int main()
{
   system("clear");

   double fahrenheit, celsius, celsius_in;
   celsius = get_celsius(double celsius_in);

   fahrenheit = celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius);

   cout << celsius << "C = " << fahrenheit << "F\n";

   return 0;
}
void celsius_to_fahrenheit(double celsius)
{
     return(celsius * (9.0/5.0) + 32.0);
}
void get_celsius(double &celsius_in)
{
    cout << "Enter the temperature in celsius: ";
    cin >> celsius_in;
}
```

Comment: your first step to fixing this would be to resolve the compiler errors you undoubtedly are getting.

Comment: well returning a value from a void function is definitely wrong.

Comment: *"Does anyone know why this is happening?"* - why what is happening? Please phrase your questions properly. Copy-paste full error messages into your post, where applicable. If the program compiles successfully, then give expected and actual behaviour for a given input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
celsius = get_celsius(double celsius_in);
```

The return type of `get_celsius` is `void`, but you are assigning to `celsius`.

Assuming you don't modify your functions (which I would recommend doing) you'd have to modify at least `main` to do this

```
get_celsius(celsius_in);
celsius = celsius_in;
fahrenheit = celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius);
```

Or better yet, `get_celsius` should just return a `double` so you can assign from it.

Answer (score 0):

`celsius = get_celsius(double celsius_in);`

get_celsius is a void function, so you are assigning nothing to `celsius`, then passing that into your convert function. Try passing `celsius_in` to your convert function.

Answer (score 0):

You declared functions celsius_to_fahrenheit and get_celsius as having return type void

```
void celsius_to_fahrenheit(double celsius);
void get_celsius(double &);
```

So you may not use them in assignment statements as you are trying to do

```
celsius = get_celsius(double celsius_in);
fahrenheit = celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius);
```

Moreover in the first assignment statement there is incorrect syntax.

Also it is not clear why you defined three variables while all what you need is to convert celsius to fahrenheit. That is it is enough to define at the most two variables.

The program could look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

double celsius_to_fahrenheit( double celsius );
double get_celsius();

int main()
{
   std::system( "cls" );

   double celsius = get_celsius();

   double fahrenheit = celsius_to_fahrenheit( celsius );

   std::cout << celsius << "C = " << fahrenheit << "F\n";

   return 0;
}

double celsius_to_fahrenheit( double celsius )
{
     return ( celsius * ( 9.0 / 5.0 ) + 32.0 );
}

double get_celsius()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the temperature in celsius: ";

    double celsius = 0.0;
    std::cin >> celsius;

    return celsius;
}
```

If you need to use references then function get_celsius could be defined as before

```
void get_celsius( double &celsius )
{
    std::cout << "Enter the temperature in celsius: ";

    celsius = 0.0;
    std::cin >> celsius;
}
```

But it has to be called the following way

```
   double celsius;
   get_celsius( celsius );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
double celsius_to_fahrenheit(double celsius);
double get_celsius(double &celsius_in);

int main()
{
`enter code here`system("clear");

`enter code here`double fahrenheit, celsius, celsius_in;
`enter code here`celsius = get_celsius(celsius_in);

`enter code here`fahrenheit = celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius);
`enter code here`cout << celsius << "C = " << fahrenheit << "F\n";

`enter code here`return 0;
}
double celsius_to_fahrenheit(double celsius)
{
`enter code here`return(celsius * (9.0/5.0) + 32.0);
}
double get_celsius(double &celsius_in)
{
`enter code here`cout << "Enter the temperature in celsius: ";
`enter code here`cin >> celsius_in;
`enter code here`return celsius_in;
}
```